# MusicKit Login to Multiple Accounts

Tags: ios, swift, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am trying to create an iOS app in swift that can retrieve information from the Apple Music API about multiple users (different accounts). For example:

- User 1 logs in
- User 2 logs in
- Make API requests to gather information about user 1 and user 2

Is this possible? I am currently using `SKCloudServiceController.requestUserToken(forDeveloperToken:, completionHandler: )` but this only allows retrieving a user token for the currently logged in user. Is there away to prompt a new user to login? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you got any solution ?. I am facing same issue. I want to same music identifier will play for all other app users.  Help me

Comment: @PankajSonava Based on my research, there is no solution to this issue and it is currently impossible to retrieve a user's userToken for an account other than the one currently logged into the device.

Comment: Ok thanks. @jeremyms